# How do I insert .html file in adobe captivate?

Tags: adobe, adobe-captivate

I am unable to insert a video which is having table of contents and is capable of playing at required time frame and that particular video is supposed to be a part of adobe captivate project. The video is embedded in a html5 file. Adding a zip file of the html5 file along with xml etc. is unable to load in Adobe Captivate. Please if someone can help me proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert HTML files, but you can insert a web object !

So you just have to publish your video on a server, to copy the link address where it is located on the internet and to insert this link in Adobe Captivate ( insert > objects > web).

Hope it will help you.